# TFS Work Item Customization: Start Date can be between Iteration Dates

Tags: tfs

In the Work Item type like Bug or Task the start date allows to select any date however we want the Work Item allows the start date to be in the date frame set for a particular Iteration.

how to set such a rule for Work item in TFS?

Comment: You can try to define your own rules using [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/intro/) some example [here](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/issues/243#issuecomment-323090724)

Comment: Thanks Jayendran we will explore this option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't such a rule/feature in TFS can achieve that, we can only apply an existing field rule to a work item type, please see [Add a rule to a work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts)

So as a workaround you can write you own rules using [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/using/writing-rules/writing-rules/) just as @Jayendran mentioned.

You can also try another workaround:

Instead of entering the start date, you can auto fill the `Start Date` field on some event (eg: when changed the state from "`New`" to "`Approved`").

For example we first open the work item and assign to Developer. When he is ready start working on the task, he will change WI state from "`New`" to "`Approved`". In this case the start will pick the current date & time. when he done the development, developer will change the WI state to "`Done`", and the end date will pick the current date & time. Thus the work item within the particular iteration, so the actually Start and End date will also between Iteration Dates

Comment: Hi Andy,Thanks for your reply the idea looks good what if when the Work item is created and someone mentions the start date by mistake is there any rule for that as well ?

Comment: @Ankit No any rules can restrict that smoothly... However I can think of is that restrict the Work item creators to change the `start date` field. See [Restrict modification of a field to a group of users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/reference/xml/apply-rule-work-item-field?view=vsts#apply-or-ignore-rules-based-on-user-or-group).

Comment: Thanks this will help!